# Assigning appSettings values to a String

Tags: vb.net, appsettings

I am getting an error. I am trying to connect to SQL SERVER with this appSettings. But this fragment of code is giving an error.

Warning 6   'Public Shared ReadOnly Property AppSettings As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings'.

[image]

`

```
Public Class clsDL

    'Fields - Data
    Private adp As SqlDataAdapter
    Private cmd As SqlCommand
    Private Cn As SqlConnection
    Private Shared db As clsDL
    Private dr As SqlDataReader
    Private ds As DataSet
    Private dt As DataTable
    Private gUserPwdSeed As Object = 10
    Private intIndex As Integer
    Private m_trans As SqlTransaction
    Private objConSettings As ConfigurationSettings
    Private strCnString As String
    Private strDatabase As String
    Private strPwd As String
    Private strServer As String
    Private strUID As String


    Private Sub Connect()
        Try
            Me.strServer = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Server")
            Me.strDatabase = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("Database")
            Me.strUID = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("UID")

    End Sub`
```

Comment: @DieterMeemken PLEASE CHECK THE QUESTION NOW....I HAVE EDITED IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the suggestion in the warning.

```
Private Sub Connect()
    Try
        Me.strServer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Server")
        Me.strDatabase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
        Me.strUID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UID")

End Sub`
```

We took that simple approach from our old codebase whilst converting up rather than rewriting and it worked fine.